# PyQt5 - Load JPEG-compressed image to QImage

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, image-compression, qimage

I have an application that displays images, using `QtGui.QImage`. To save space, I changed the GeoTiff compression from `LZW` to `JPEG`, but now I get the following error:

```
foo: JPEG compression support is not configured.
foo: Sorry, requested compression method is not configured.
```

I have not found anything how I can configure PyQt to understand that type of compression. Do I need a specific build or can I set it somewhere?
Using Python 3.10 with PyQt5.15

Comment: Seems a known and still unresolved bug, see [QTBUG-57712](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57712): the support is not enabled by default in the configuration, so right now the only option you have (besides recompiling Qt on your own, which I wouldn't suggest) is to use an alternate reading method (PIL should be able to handle it) and convert it to a QImage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of [@musicamante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001654/musicamante), the issue could be solved simply by using:

```
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt

my_q_image = ImageQt(image_path)
```

Then, `my_q_image` acts exactly like a `QImage`.

**Important** reminder though, which I found while investigating this: PyQt5 support from `PIL` ends in July 2023!